# Converter um array de números em uma única String em php

Tags: php, array, string, mysqli

como eu transformo um array de números em um única string em php?

No código abaixo a variável $result é o array de números, e tentei converter ele para uma única string com a função implode(). Mas parece que não funciona, pois o php dá a mensagem 'Notice: Array to string conversion in..."  (LINHA DA QUERY

E no banco de dados não deu certo a persistência...

Como fazer essa conversão?

```
//Result é o array de números. Preciso convertê-lo para uma String...
$resultado = implode($result);

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO forum (codUsuario,titulo,mensagem) VALUES('$result','$titulo','$mensagem');");
```

Comment: Faltou passar por qual delimitador a string deve ser juntada. `$resultado = implode(',', $result);`

Comment: Os números devem ficar concatenados sem delimitadores...

Comment: Por exemplo, se tenho um array array = [1, 2, 3]; Quero uma string "123"

Comment: Vc precisa de um delimitador, antes de salvar no banco pode dar str_replace para removê-lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na função implode, eu coloquei o delimitador vazio e deu certo:

```
$resultado = implode('', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está incluindo o `$result` na query e não o `$resultado`, você está fazendo:

```
$resultado = implode($result);

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT forum (...) VALUES('$result','$titulo','$mensagem');");
                                                 ^^^^
```

Basta alterar para `$resultado` e irá funcionar normalmente. O `implode`, como documentado, aceita inverter os parâmetros. Isso é, tanto `implode($array, '')` quanto `implode('', $array)` funcionam, assim como apenas usar o `implode($array)` neste caso.

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção - não precisa de delimitador

[**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/r5Laey)

```
$meuArray = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$result="";
foreach( $meuArray  as  $valor ) {
    $result .= $valor;
}
echo $result; // 123
```

[**Sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22f7a65139ea40f8ef665fc53c9af16bc249639e)

```
$meuArray =  [1, 2, 3];
$result="";
foreach( $meuArray  as  $valor ) {
    $result .= $valor;
}
echo $result;
```